# Any better way to pass data from a child component to a function in a parent component without using bind()?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `React.Context` to pass a function down to child component which is inside another component. See figure down below. 
I'm quite not comfortable using `.bind()` in order to pass the name variable to the function in the parent component.

Is there a better way to pass data from a child component to a function in a parent component without using `.bind()`?

See my code below:

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react'

const AppContext = createContext()

class ComponentOne extends Component {

    const handleClick = (name)=> {
        alert(`Hello ${name}`)
    }

    render(){

        return(
            <AppContext.Provider 
              value={{
                  handleClick: this.handleClick
              }}>
              <p>Hello from ComponentOne</p>
            </AppContext.Provider>

        )
    }
}

const ComponentThree = props=> {
    const name = "lomse"

    return(
       <AppContext.Consumer>
          (context=>(
             <button onClick={context.handleClick.bind(null, name)}>Click me!</button>
          ))
       </AppContext.Consumer>
    )

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do:

```
const ComponentThree = props=> {
    const name = "lomse"
    return(
       <AppContext.Consumer>
          (context=> {
             const handleClick = () => context.handleClick(name)
             return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</button>
          })
       </AppContext.Consumer>
    )

}
```

What you're doing is about binding arguments so when a function is called later it will be called with those arguments. It has nothing to do with React Context.

and onClick needs to be a function, that will be called - well - on click.

Or you could do:

```
 const handleClick = (name) => () => {
    alert(`Hello ${name}`)
 }
```

and then:

```
const ComponentThree = props=> {
    const name = "lomse"
    return(
       <AppContext.Consumer>
          (context=> (
             <button onClick={context.handleClick(name)}>Click me!</button>
          ))
       </AppContext.Consumer>
    )

}
```